# Derivative of a quadratic-like function of matrix w.r.t matrix

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, jacobian

My prime problem is to minimize a cost function $$f(X) = \left(v - Xu\right)^T\left(B + XAX^T\right)^{-1}\left(v - Xu\right)$$
where $v,u\in \mathbb{R}^3$,$A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ are positive definite, and the variable $X \in SO(3)$ is a $3\times3$ rotation matrix satisfying $X^TX=I$.

The dual problem is finding the Jacobian matrix of $f(X)$. I would like to get an explicit expression, but I found no proper way to achieve that limited by my knowledge.

I will be very appreciated if someone could show me how to make this derivation step by step. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You will have to do it in index notation, as even though the end product will be a matrix, the answer will involve contractions of rank 3 and 5 tensors.

Comment: Using index notation seems as difficult as using matrix symbols for me, because the middle part involves an inverse.I fail to imagine how to unfold the inverse using indexed elements as well. @NinadMunshi

Comment: Chain rule is not difficult. $$\nabla_u A^{-1}(u) = -A^{-2}(u)\cdot \nabla_u A(u)$$ Of course such a calculation in index notation would be easier because order would not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried http://www.matrixcalculus.org and it gave the very complicated answer

$  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial X} = -(\mathrm{inv}(B+X\cdot A\cdot X^\top )\cdot (v-X\cdot u)\cdot u^\top +\mathrm{inv}(B^\top +X\cdot A^\top \cdot X^\top )\cdot (v-X\cdot u)\cdot ((v-X\cdot u)^\top \cdot \mathrm{inv}(B^\top +X\cdot A^\top \cdot X^\top )\cdot X\cdot A^\top )+\mathrm{inv}(B+X\cdot A\cdot X^\top )\cdot (v-X\cdot u)\cdot ((v-X\cdot u)^\top \cdot \mathrm{inv}(B+X\cdot A\cdot X^\top )\cdot X\cdot A)+\mathrm{inv}(B^\top +X\cdot A^\top \cdot X^\top )\cdot (v-X\cdot u)\cdot u^\top )$

without the steps.

Where the input is (v-X*u)'*inv(B+X*A*X')*(v-X*u), where the prime denotes the transpose.

But it still doesn't give an explicit expression for $X$, when the derivative equals the $0$ matrix.

Maybe https://www.geno-project.org will help.

Comment: Very useful sites for validating handcraft derivatives, I've saved them on my bookmarks, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\skew#1{\op{skew}\LR{#1}}
\def\cay#1{\op{cay}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\C{C^{-1}}
\def\l{\lambda}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
w &= Xu-v &\qiq &\;\;dw \;= dX\,u \\
C &= {XAX^T+B} &\qiq &\;\;dC\;= 2\,\sym{dX\,AX^T} \\
&&\qiq&d\C = -\C\,dC\;\C \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
H &= 2\LR{\C ww^T\C XA - \C wu^T} \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
and the Sym, Skew, and Cayley transformations
$$\eqalign{
\sym{A} &\equiv \fracLR{A+A^T}2
, \qquad \skew{A} \equiv \fracLR{A-A^T}2 \\
\cay{A} &\equiv \LR{I+A}^{-1}\LR{I-A} \;=\; \LR{I-A}\LR{I+A}^{-1} \\
}$$
as well as the versatile Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
\sym A:B &= A:\sym B \\
\skew A:B &= A:\skew B \\
}$$
To satisfy the constraint, introduce an **unconstrained** matrix $Y$ and use it to construct $X$
$$\eqalign{
&X = \cay{2\skew Y} \qiq I = X^TX,\quad \det(X) = {\tt1} \\
\\
&X = \LR{I+Y-Y^T}^{-1}\LR{I-Y+Y^T} \\
&dX = \LR{I+Y-Y^T}^{-1}\,\BR{dY^T-dY}\:\LR{I+X} \\
&\quad\;\; = -2\,\LR{I+Y^T-Y}^{-T}\,\skew{dY}\:\LR{I+X^T}^T \\
\\
&G \equiv 2\skew{\LR{I+Y^T-Y}^{-1}H\LR{I+X^T}} \\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to  rewrite the cost function.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.

$\big(A,B,C\,$ are symmetric, which simplifies some of the steps$\big)$
$$\eqalign{
f &= ww^T:\C \\
df &= \C:2\sym{dw\;w^T} \;+\; ww^T:d\C \\
 &= 2\C w:dw \;-\; ww^T:\C\,dC\;\C \\
 &= 2\C w:{dX\,u} \;-\; \C ww^T\C:2\sym{dX\,AX^T} \\
 &= \LR{2\C wu^T - 2\C ww^T\C XA}:dX \\
 &= -H:dX \\
 &= +H:2\,\LR{I+Y^T-Y}^{-T}\,\skew{dY}\:\LR{I+X^T}^T \\
 &= 2\LR{I+Y^T-Y}^{-1}H\LR{I+X^T}:\skew{dY} \\
 &= 2\skew{\LR{I+Y^T-Y}^{-1}H\LR{I+X^T}}:dY \\
 &= G:dY \\
\grad{f}{Y} &= G \\
}$$
The gradient $G$ is a rather complicated function of $Y$, so obtaining a closed-form solution for the *zero gradient condition* is unlikely.

However, a **numerical** solution via gradient descent is simple
$$\eqalign{
&Y_{\tt1} = random \\
&{\rm for\;} k = {\tt1}\;{\rm to}\;k_{max} \\
&\qquad G_k = G(Y_k) \\
&\qquad Y_{k+1} = Y_{k} - \l_k G_k \\
}$$
The iteration can terminate early if $\|G_k\|$ gets small enough.

The steplength $\l_k$ is specified by the descent algorithm
([Barzilai-Borwein](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barzilai-Borwein_method) is my favorite).

All of the algebraic complexity (derived above) is hidden behind the function call $\;G(Y_k)$.

Internally the function uses $Y$ to sequentially calculate $\,X,w,C,H,{\,\rm\,and\:then\;}G$.

Once the optimal $Y$ has been obtained, the corresponding orthogonal matrix can be constructed
$$ X = \LR{I+Y-Y^T}^{-1}\LR{I-Y+Y^T} $$